# DD-WRT Router acting as a Switch and Wi-Fi AP

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking, home-networking, dd-wrt

Recently I upgraded to Comcast Business and their modem has a built-in router so I took off my [DD-WRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT) router and moved to a location in my home where I needed more ports and [Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) (preferably without running new Ethernet cables since it's 50-100 foot run through floor and ceilings).

I have my network cable from my Comcast modem going into Port 1 of my DD-WRT router with Port 2 and 3 being networked PCs. I have DD-WRT setup as a [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) forwarder with the firewall disabled. This lets my all of my devices access the network fine. Is the correct the way to do this? Or is this a less optimal solution and it should be done in a slightly different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're OK with the Comcast modem's firewalling capabilities then that sounds fine.  If it were my network, I would disable the modem's routing and do all the [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)'ing on the DD-WRT router because I'm picky about my firewall rules.

Comment: Sadly it seems my DD-WRT can't handle using about 100% of my bandwidth in full duplex on bittorrent without causing http traffic to be brought to a crawl (I already up'd the connection limit to 4096) one of my other posts I considered getting a business class router or building one with Untangle but everything seems fine with my new modem I still might be an Untangle server later on to handle advanced routing/QoS etc.